# How can I find out if the mouse position is the same as an image without having to click on it? JS

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouseevent, event-listener

I have a game in which the player has to click on an image to either get points or loose lives depending on the image they click, but I think this is too easy.

I tried re-writing the code so the event listener captures the mouse position even if the player doesn't click so it will be registered before they even think about it.
Here is what I have so far:

`cv.addEventListener('mouseover',MousePos);`

```
function MousePos(e) {
    var posX= e.clientX - cv.offsetLeft;
    var posY= e.clientY - cv.offsetTop;
    for (var i = 0; i<personagensExib.length; i++) {
        fig=personagensExib[i][0];
        px=personagensExib[i][1];
        py=personagensExib[i][2]

        if ((posX>= px && posX <=(px+tamanhoAw)) &&
        (posY>= py && posY <=(py+tamanhoAh))){
            console.log("clicou")
            pontuar();
            personagensExib.splice(s,1)
            return
        }
    };
}
```

console shows no errors but it's not working either. 
(tamanhoAw and tamanhoAh are the size of the images. 
personagensExib[] is an array of the images that will appear on the canvas.)

Comment: did you actually register a `mousemove` event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

Comment: Instead of `console.log("clicou")` do a `console.log(posX,posY)` and you'll see that the position is the point where the mouse is entering the canvas. Stick with a click or a mousedown event. Alternatively you may try mousemove